# Is there a command line I can run to list the size of the mail dir for each cpanel account?

Tags: ssh, cpanel, whm

I have ~100 accounts on a dedicated VPS. I'd like to see a list of all accounts, ordered by who has the biggest mail directory. I do not need to see details of individual mail accounts; just want to identify the cpanel accounts with the biggest Mail directory by KB. Hope that's clear! I have hunted around but haven't found an explicit answer to this question.
(I'm capable at running command lines in SSH but not an expert. I'd appreciate a clear and complete answer, if one exists. I like to understand what each part of the command is doing).
Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this line of piped commands in a WHM/cPanel server via SSH:

```
find /home -maxdepth 2 -type d | grep "/mail$" | xargs du -s | sort -n -r
```

where:

- **find /home -maxdepth 2 -type d**: Will find all directories inside */home*
  folder (usually the cpanel accounts folder) but only 2 levels of directories as maximum below the */home*, like */home/account1/mail* or */home/account1/public_html*.
- **grep "/mail$"**: Filter the previous *find* result selecting only the directories that ends in */mail* string, like */home/account1/mail* or */home/account2/mail*. cPanel use that *mail* directory to store emails accounts.
- **xargs du -s**: Execute a calculation of the size of each one of the directories filtered by the previous *grep*.
- **sort -n -r**: Sorts the output of the previous *xargs* command by number in reverse mode, showing the biggest first.